# Vertex Skinning Looks Messy on Real Android Device using Monodroid

Tags: c#, glsl, opengl-es2, mono, xamarin

I have no problem doing the "vertex skinning" for three-dimensional animation. All goes **well** when using the **emulator** (and genymotion). However, when run on a **real device** (such as Samsung and Lenovo) looks **messy**.

### Screenshoot (Emulator)

[image: Emulator]

### Screenshoot (Real device)

[image: Device]

### Passing skin transform matrix

```
int location = ...;
int arrayCount = ...;
float[] skinTransform = ...;
GL.UniformMatrix4(location, arrayCount, false, skinTransform);
```

### GLSL vertex

```
uniform mat4 World;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Bones[20];

attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 BoneIndices;
attribute vec4 BoneWeights;
attribute vec2 UV;
varying vec4 v_Position;
varying vec2 v_UV;

void main()
{
    mat4 skinTransform;
    int boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.x);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.x;
    boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.y);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.y;
    boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.z);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.z;
    boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.w);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.w;
    vec4 skinPos = Position * skinTransform;
    vec4 worldPosition = skinPos * World;
    vec4 viewPosition = worldPosition * View;
    v_Position = viewPosition * Projection;
    v_UV = UV;
    gl_Position = v_Position;
}
```

### APK

http://1drv.ms/1BzYV3Q
**Touch** screen to **on/off** animation.

### Info

1. Xamarin.Android = 4.10.x.x
2. Emulator Target = API 16 or 4.1
3. Real device Target = API 16 or 4.1
4. App Target = API 10 or 2.3 (tested also in API 14 and API 16), **results remain the same**

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Best regards and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is in the uninitialized variable *skinTransform*. You should always explicitly initialize all your variables.
So, you need to define and initialize the variable *skinTransform* like this:

```
mat4 skinTransform(0.0);
```

See  [The OpenGL ES Shading Language](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) documentation at section  *5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors* for more information.

In addition, linear blending of transformation matrices is not a good idea for several reasons. Try to blend position values instead.

Comment: I think the result of mutiplying the position by the weighted sum of the matrices is exactly the same as calculating a weighted sum of the products of the position and each matrix. But you're right about initializing the matrix to zero.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Adreno GPUs.

Your problem is this little snippet of code:

```
Bones[boneIndex]
```

Many Adreno GPUs have a bug when accessing `mat4` uniform arrays with non-constant indices. They will always silently return the first element in the array. [This discussion](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/mobile-technologies/mobile-gaming-graphics-optimization-adreno/27169) on the qualcomm forums has some more background on this problem.

This bug applies only to uniform arrays of `mat4`. A known workaround is to encode each matrix as four `vec4` instead, as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823743/conversion-from-float-to-int-weird-behavior)

Another way to solve this problem is to encode your matrices in `OES_texture_float` textures, as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509979/skeletal-animation-on-gpu-for-android-opengl-es). However, not all devices support `OES_texture_float`, and not all devices (including many Samsung devices) support accessing texture units from the vertex shader.

There is some more information in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/77854/how-can-i-reliably-implement-gpu-skinning-in-android) I posted a while ago.